# Reinstall Arch Linux without losing downloaded packages

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I was installing Arch Linux when the Internet went down. I was unable to download all the required packages. Over 70% of packages were downloaded. I'm trying to reinstall it with the command:

```
pacstrap /mnt base base-devel
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to setup chroot /mnt
```

I don't want to re-download the packages I've previously downloaded because of limited internet bandwidth.

How can I reinstall Arch Linux without losing the downloaded packages?

Comment: Just re-enter the chroot and complete the install: your packages are still there. Alternatively (but only if you are confident in what you are doing), mount the target filesystem and use `pacman --root /path/to/mounted/root`...

Comment: I'm not sure where those packages are actually stored during installation. But you should check /var/cache/pkg folder if its not empty. Also, I think (I'm not sure about pacstrap command), if you didn't reformat the partition you want to install arch, just rerunning the command should return to downloading the next missing package (see download size before confirmation).

Comment: Assuming all the package files are still there you can use pacman directly (pacstrap is just a wrapper script for pacman) to install the packages on the new system. Just check the pacman man pages for the proper flags